# How this jquery code will work?

Tags: jquery

```
<a id="page-help" href="page.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'popupwindow', 'width=500,height=300'); return false;">what is this?</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page-help').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

please see the above code and tell me how it works.  as far my knowledge it seems when page load then a jquery dialog will be created and loaded but will be shown when user click on the link. am i right if yes then this approach will not be good because if i attach this way jquery code with all links in my page then many jquery dialog will load in page with content and that may slow down the page loading......am i right?

Comment: IDs must be unique so what the point of using `each`.

Comment: In this particular case the `.each` loop will iterate over a collection of one element, so no worries. But if you had a different selector, for example `$('a[href]').each(...)` it would be what you expect: load the resources linked by each link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right, but it wouldn't be a problem when you only have one dialog to preload, which would be the case when using an ID as a selector.

If you had more than one it would be more optimal to load the contents only after the user has clicked on a link, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel=dialog]').on('click', function(e){
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });
         e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It would work assuming you have your links marked like `<a href="contents.html" rel="dialog">`

Comment: what is rel=dialog ? how my hyperlink should look like?

Comment: Sorry, just have edited in the answer to this :) It's an alternative to using class names for everything, andt the construct `a[rel="dialog"]` is known as "attribute selector" in CSS.

Comment: another issue i think in ur code. suppose when user click first time on the link then dialog appear but if again click on that link after closing dialog then what happen ? in ur code div is created on the fly.so if i click as many time on the link then a div will be appended to body and that may cause problem. i guess u need to edit your code in such a way as a result if user click many time on the link then no problem should occur. what is ur suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

you are right, but the code isn't! for starters the code must be included inside a `<script></script>` tag, secondly as @Satpal mentioned in the comments, ids must be unique, so instead of `id`, you must use `class` or remove the `.each`.

and finally, no matter how you implement the jQuery or JS code to your html, it's gonna take some time to load!